# How to restrict free shipping if the minimum order value below as defined after coupon code apply in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, coupon-codes, free-shipping

I have enabled free shipping when minimum order value above $500. Which is working fine.

but if customer applied any discount coupon and total order value below $500 then free shipping should not apply because grand total is less than $500.

For now, Free shipping still applying because Subtotal is still greater than $500.

Can anyone help me how to remove free shipping if Grand total less than $500 after applying discount coupon?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the sort order of the `Marketing -> Sales ->Checkout Totals Sort Order` in the admin panel. Have the `Discount` field sort order value set before the `Sub Total` sort order value. This way we will have the Subtotal contain the discount applied.
[image]

Comment: Do you understand my question? you are saying about swapping the position of subtotal and discount.